# Bargaining Theory: reading list

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, reference-request, bargaining

I looked around in the forum but I have not found this question yet. I would like to approach the topic of bargaining models in the spirit of Rubinstein, Ariel. "Perfect equilibrium in a bargaining model." Econometrica: Journal of the Econometric Society (1982): 97-109.

I have studied game theory but never actually worked with these kind of models (see for example: Chae, Suchan, and Paul Heidhues. "Buyers' alliances for bargaining power." Journal of Economics & Management Strategy 13.4 (2004): 731-754.)

I have done some timid google scholar searches, but I have found so much material that I cannot skim it on my own. Could you suggest a reading list of the main references that are a must read for these kind of models?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Osborne and Rubinstein has a book called "Bargaining and Markets" where they have a detailed exposition on bargaining models. I think its free to download from Ariel's website. Apart from that, Abhinay Muthoo has a very nice book on bargaining: "Bargaining Theory with Applications".

You can always look up chapters on bargaining in Tirole's Game Theory or Myerson's Game Theory books. They're short, but quite detailed to develop the basic toolkits.